# Find the probability fewer than half the villagers have the eye disorder? (binomial)

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-theorem

In a certain african village, 80% of the villagers are known to have a particular eye disorder. 12 people are waiting to see the nurse.

$a)$ What is the most likely number to have the disorder?

$b)$ Find the probability that fewer than half have the eye disorder.

$c)$ Find the probability that 2 persons do not have the disorder.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **Hint for a):** The mode of the binomial distribution is $\lfloor n\cdot p+p  \rfloor $ Does it help ?

Comment: i know a) is 10 since u=n*p

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. If $n=8$ and $p=0.2$, then the maximum probability is at $x=1$:$P(X=1)=0.3721$

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the formula you can calculate $ P(X=x)$, for $x=9,10,11$. If $P(X=9)<P(X=10)>P(X=11)$, then $P(X=10)$ is the maximum. Note that the binomial distribution is a unimodal distribution.  For $b)$ you have to calculate $ P(X<6)= \sum_{k=0}^{5} 0.8^k\cdot 0.2^{12-k}$. And for **c)** you calculate the probability, that $10(=12-2)$ persons **do** have the disorder: $P(X=10)$

Comment: The integer part of $13(.8)$ is the $mode,$ the value of $x$ at which $P(X=x)$ is a maximum. The value $12(.8)$, whether integer or not is the $mean$. These are different concepts.

Comment: Why are 12 villagers waiting to see the nurse?  If all villagers see the nurse regularly and this is a random sample then the answer will be different than if she only sees villagers with eye problems or if she only sees villagers who are not known to have this particular eye disorder.

Answer (score 2):

By now, I'm guessing this is a problem from a book at a more elementary
level than the Comments. (That's why we ask for 'context' as in
one of the Comments. Without context it is not so easy to be helpful.)

Use the binomial formula to make a distribution table for the
random variable $X \sim Binom(n = 12, p = .8),$ where $X$ is the number among 12 who have the disorder. Alternatively, depending on what text you are using,
you may have such a table in an Appendix at the back of your text.

One example of using the binomial formula is
$$P(X = 11) = {12 \choose 11}(.8)^{11}(.2) =  0.2061584.$$

Below is a table I made using statistical software. It has six-place
accuracy. You may want to round your answers to four places.

```
   x  P( X = x )
   1    0.000000
   2    0.000004
   3    0.000058
   4    0.000519
   5    0.003322
   6    0.015502
   7    0.053150
   8    0.132876
   9    0.236223
  10    0.283468
  11    0.206158
  12    0.068719
```

(a) Find the biggest probability in the list. Answer is 10 patients.

(b) Half would be 6. Fewer than half would be 0, 1, 2, ..., or 5.
Add probabilities for these six values of X. $P(X=0)$ is missing
from the table because, as for $P(X=1),$ the probability is
negligibly small. (Your sum should a little less than 0.04.)

(c) If exactly 2 do not, then exactly 10 do. What is the
probability of that?

Now is the time to look in your text or lecture notes to see
if anything I have said matches what is there, and how you
might have worked out the answer on your own.